# How to show horizontal grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview, gridview

How to Show the Grid in asp page in a horizontal manner with page size =3. is there a grid property which help me to show Grid in horizontal way? i have used the following  property of Grid :

```
   AlternatingRowStyle-HorizontalAlign, EditRowStyle-HorizontalAlign etc
```

But it is not helpful. How can i show the grid in horizontal way? I am new Developer and i am not been able to do this. i have googled but cant find the appropriate one. 
I want my grid something like this 
[image]

I want Column to be added instead of row. I have a Datatable which store Data Like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataList` or `Repeater` control instead of `Gridview`.
By using grid view  you cant achieve this.